# disable IP forwarding if no port mapping definition in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am learning docker network. I created a simple `docker-compose` file that starts two tomcat containers:

```
version: '3'
services:
    tomcat-server-1:
        container_name: tomcat-server-1
        image: .../apache-tomcat-10.0:1.0
        ports:
            - "8001:8080"

    tomcat-server-2:
        container_name: tomcat-server-2
        image: .../apache-tomcat-10.0:1.0
```

After I start the containers with `docker-compose up` I can see that `tomcat-server-1` responses on http://localhost:8001. At the first glance, the `tomcat-server-2` is not available from localhost. That great, this is what I need.

When I inspect the two running containers I can see that they use the following internal IPs:

- tomcat-server-1: 172.18.0.2
- tomcat-server-2: 172.18.0.3

I see that the `tomcat-server-1` is available from the host machine via http://172.18.0.2:8080 as well.

**Then the following surprised me:**
The `tomcat-server-2` is also available from the host machine vie http://172.18.0.3:8080 despite port mapping is not defined for this container in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

**What I would like to reach is the following:**

- The two tomcat servers must see each other in the internal docker network via hostnames.
- Tomcat must be available from the host machine ONLY if the port mapping is defined in the docker-compose file, eg.: "8001:8080".
- If no port mapping definition then the container could NOT be unavailable. Either from localhost or its internal IP, eg.: 172.18.0.3.

I have tried to use different network configurations like the bridge, none, and host mode. No success.

Of course, the `host` mode can not work because both tomcat containers use internally the same port 8080. So if I am correct then only `bridge` or `none` mode that I can consider.

Is that possible to configure the docker network this way?
That would be great to solve this via only the docker-compose file without any external docker, iptable, etc. manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without additional firewalling setup, you can't prevent a Linux-native host from reaching the container-private IP addresses.

That having been said, the container-private IP addresses are extremely limited.  You can't reach them from other hosts.  If Docker is running in a Linux VM (as the Docker Desktop application provides on MacOS or Windows) then the host outside the VM can't reach them either.  In most cases I would recommend against looking up the container-private IP addresses up at all since they're not especially useful.

I wouldn't worry about this case too much.  If your security requirements need you to prevent non-Docker host processes from contacting the containers, then you probably also have pretty strict controls over what's actually running on the host and who can log in; you shouldn't have unexpected host processes that might be trying to connect to the containers.